# Select and count the number of duplicate items with two different outcome values?

Tags: r, subset

Long-time follower, thanks so much for all your help over the years! I have a question that might have an easy answer, but I failed in googling it, and trying various subsetting and bracket notation also feel short.  I'm betting someone here has encountered a similar problem.

**I have a long-form data set with a set of duplicate ids.**  I also have a third variable that might be different for the duplicate.  By example, if you recreate my data set:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d")
y <- c("z", "z", "z", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x")
z <- c(10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20)
df <- cbind(x, y, z)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- c("id1", "id2", "var1") 
df
```

I want to select the rows in which id2 has BOTH a 10 and 20 when they are connected to the same id1,  For example, **'x' has two observations connected to id1 ('a') with two different var1 values (a '10' and a '20).**

I want to select these cases, as well as count how many cases like this are in the overall data set.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is with `ddply` from the `plyr` package. Something like this:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(df, c('id2', 'id1'), function(x) if(length(unique(x$var1))==2) x)
  id1 id2 var1
1   d   x   10
2   d   x   20
3   a   z   10
4   a   z   20
```